# Azure request routing for a blog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, url-routing, arr

I'm using Azure to host my MVC5 website at

*mysite.com*

I want to host a WordPress site at

*mysite.com/blog*

but, for security reasons, I don't want to host my MVC5 app and WordPress on the same instance.

I don't want to go down the route of a seperate subdomain for the blog.

How should I go about this? 
Can Azure Application Request Routing do this sort of thing?